# Swift MacOX - Popover segue creates multiple view controller instances without destroying them when they are dismissed

Tags: swift, macos, segue, popover, nsviewcontroller

I'm creating a popover style view controller in storyboard like this

[image]

Then I click the button, the view controller shows and when I click anywhere outside, the view controller is "dismissed".

However, when I click the button again, a new instance of the view controller is lunched and the previous one is still running. I have tried `deinit` but it's not getting called when the view controller is "dismissed".

How can I either destroy the view controller instance when clicking outside, or "show" the already created instance?

My code in the view controller:

```
class FileTransViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.25, target: self, selector: #selector(updateProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        //print(123)
        print("\(self)")
    }

    deinit {
        print("destroyed")
        if let timer = timer {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

    @objc func updateProgress() {
        print("updating progress")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with popovers. You are leaking because you retain the timer while the timer retains you — a classic retain cycle.

To break the cycle, you must invalidate the timer. You cannot do this in `deinit`, because by definition it cannot be called until after you break the cycle. `NSPopover.willCloseNotification` might be a good opportunity.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the hint! I was able to break the circle during `NSPopover.willCloseNotification`

Answer (score 1):

As @matt says, you have problem with retain cycle. You can avoid it using `Timer` with block where you can declare `weak` reference for `self`

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.25, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
    guard let self = self else {
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }
    print("updating progress")
}
```

---

You also don't need `deinit` in this case since you're invalidating timer inside `guard`'s `else` block and you also don't need variable `timer` and you can just write `Timer` if you don't want to invalidate timer manually somewhere else

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(...) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this answer too!

Comment: @Fangming you also don't need `deinit` in this case since you're invalidating it inside `guard else` block. You also don't need variable for `timer` and you can just write `Timer` if you don't want to invalidate timer manually somewhere else

Comment: Yup. Thanks! A lot cleaner now

Comment: Yes, this approach is illustrated by my example project https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p498timerLeaker2/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/FlipsideViewController.swift. The other approach is illustrated by https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p498timerLeaker/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/FlipsideViewController.swift.

Comment: @matt yes, thank you for this comment. Anyway, I like with my approach that you don't need variable for `Timer` and you can simply invalidate it if `self` gets deinitialized and you can also get rid of declaring `deinit`